# Command to convert an input into sequential numbering

Tags: numbering

Is there a command able to convert an input into sequential numbering (and when that input is used again the command will recall the previously assigned number)?

Context: I have various scientific experiments discussed. In the source TEX file, I'm using the experiment number referred to my lab notebook, but in the final PDF I would like them to be sequentially numbered. Clearly, I would like the same number to be used for the same experiment. The first time the experiment is mentioned it should receive a new progressive number, otherwise it should recall the number it was assigned to him.

```
% the \magicnumbering is a command name that I invented for this purpose!

\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

I did \magicnumbering{experimentA} before \magicnumbering{experimentB}, but \magicnumbering{experimentC} was done even before \magicnumbering{experimentA}.

\end{document}
```

I would like this MWE to print out:

> I did 1 before 2, but 3 was done even before 1.

I'm sure there is a very simple solution that I can't find. I'm sorry for my ignorance, I wish you could help.

Answer (score 1):

The following does this by storing the keys in a property list (using `expl3`). To change the formatting of the output, you can change the definition of `\magicnumbering_output:n`.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_magicnumbering_numbers_prop
\int_new:N \g_magicnumbering_current_int
\tl_new:N \l_magicnumbering_output_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \magicnumbering_output:n #1
  {
    #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \magicnumbering_output:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \magicnumbering_parse:n #1
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF
      \g_magicnumbering_numbers_prop {#1} \l_magicnumbering_output_tl
      { \magicnumbering_output:V \l_magicnumbering_output_tl }
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g_magicnumbering_current_int
        \prop_put:NnV
          \g_magicnumbering_numbers_prop {#1} \g_magicnumbering_current_int
        \magicnumbering_output:V \g_magicnumbering_current_int
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \magicnumbering { m } { \magicnumbering_parse:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
I did \magicnumbering{experimentA} before \magicnumbering{experimentB}, but
\magicnumbering{experimentC} was done even before
\magicnumbering{experimentA}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `seq` should be `prop`. I'd also put the code now in `\NewDocumentCommand` in a function. In general, `\NewDocumentCommand` should only be used for normalizing arguments or for doing simple tasks.

Comment: @egreg of course. What a stupid typo... :) I honestly don't see any advantage of moving the code into another function here, though.

Comment: Following guidelines? :-)

Comment: @egreg ew, guidelines :) I'd argue that 9 lines of code is a simple task.